# Mutual Exclusion Problem

Tags: mutex

Please take a look on the following pseudo-code:

```
boolean blocked[2];
int turn;
void P(int id) {
      while(true) {
             blocked[id] = true;
             while(turn != id) {
                    while(blocked[1-id])
                    /* do nothing */;
                    turn = id;
             }
             /* critical section */
             blocked[id] = false;
             /* remainder */
      }
}
void main() {
      blocked[0] = false;
      blocked[1] = false;
      turn = 0;
      parbegin(P(0), P(1)); //RUN P0 and P1 parallel
}
```

I thought that a could implement a simple Mutual - Exclution solution using the code above. But it's not working. Has anyone got an idea why?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Please post *real* code rather than pseudo-code, and specify the language. Multi-threading is prone to very subtle bugs - seeing the *exact* code is critical.

Comment: I've made this mistake before(posting psudo) and in the process of putting up the real code found the problem.

So please, real code.

Comment: Also, how can you tell it isn't working?

Comment: By not working you mean, ...?

Comment: the program was written in C and I'm unable to post the source because it's really long. The problem is, that at some point both procedures access the critical section...

Comment: what platform is this on? surely your platform supports a mutex of sorts.

Comment: The algorithm is Hyman's algorithm, which was published by the ACM and later it was realized the algorithm is flawed. You don't need the source code--pseudo code works fine-- and it has nothing to do with compilers or platform.

Comment: This is clearly homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutual Exclusion is in this exemple not guaranteed because of the following:

We begin with the following situation:

```
blocked = {false, false};
turn = 0;
```

P1 is now executes, and skips

```
  blocked[id] = false; // Not yet executed.
```

The situation is now:

```
blocked {false, true}
turn = 0;
```

Now P0 executes. It passes the second while loop, ready to execute the critical section. And when P1 executes, it sets turn to 1, and is also ready to execute the critical section.

Btw, this method was originally invented by Hyman. He sent it to Communications of the Acm in 1966

Answer (score 2):

Mutual Exclusion is in this exemple not guaranteed because of the following:

We begin with the following situation:

```
turn= 1;
blocked = {false, false};
```

The execution runs as follows:

```
P0: while (true) {
P0:   blocked[0] = true;
P0:   while (turn != 0) {
P0:     while (blocked[1]) {
P0:     }
P1: while (true) {
P1:   blocked[1] = true;
P1:   while (turn != 1) {
P1:   }
P1:   criticalSection(P1);
P0:     turn = 0;
P0:   while (turn != 0)
P0:   }
P0:   critcalSection(P0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework, or some embedded platform? Is there any reason why you can't use pthreads or Win32 (as relevant) synchronisation primitives?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to declare blocked and turn as volatile, but without specifying the programming language there is no way to know.

Answer (score -1):

Concurrency can not be implemented like this, especially in a multi-processor (or multi-core) environment: different cores/processors have different caches. Those caches may not be coherent. The pseudo-code below could execute in the order shown, with the results shown:

```
get blocked[0] -> false   // cpu 0
set blocked[0] = true     // cpu 1 (stored in CPU 1's L1 cache)
get blocked[0] -> false   // cpu 0 (retrieved from CPU 0's L1 cache)
get glocked[0] -> false   // cpu 2 (retrieved from main memory)
```

You *need* hardware knowledge to implement concurrency.

Answer (score -1):

Compiler might have optimized out the "empty" while loop.  Declaring variables as volatile might help, but is not guaranteed to be sufficient on multiprocessor systems.